# DVWP, xsl choose

Tags: data-view-web-part, custom-form, form, workflow

I'm looking at building a solution that will use this as it's base:
[Content Types as Statuses](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157-7d96-4e15-a987-54b8a3e4d948&ID=49)

and I'd like to know if it's possible to create a DVWP form that only allows the first form, eg the initial status, to be filled out.  After the initial status is created, when displaying the form, have a workflow button connect to an initiation form, which will in turn update the item and content type.  I'll need to not let the form display the 2nd or 3rd status until the first is completed.  Is this possible?  Or a better question, does this question make sense LOL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question(s), you probably can do what you want.  You'll want to use either script or customize the form and manage things in the XSL for the different item statuses.  You could probably just build one big DVWP with conditional logic (xsl:choose) to call different rendering templates (the XSL kind) based on the value of the status column.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance.  I'm thinking DVWP with conditioning logic is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove or exclude that field from the update version of the form.